# Is it possible to use a image by cropping to fixed size

Tags: php

I have two different images, one is in my local machine and another is in web. I want to merge these two image, I have everything but my problem is these two two image is not same width and height. My local image is a mask and the online image need to fit with local. Local image dimension 400x400.

**Problems:** If the online image dimension is lower/greater then the local one then the image just take the actual size, not fit into the mask image.

Now what should i do to make these image fit to each other?

[My output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OWlF.png)

What i try is [Collected from web]-

```
//define the width and height of our images
define("WIDTH", 400);
define("HEIGHT", 400);

$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

//make sure the transparency information is saved
imagesavealpha($dest_image, true);

//create a fully transparent background (127 means fully transparent)
$trans_background = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);

//fill the image with a transparent background
imagefill($dest_image, 0, 0, $trans_background);

//take create image resources out of the 3 pngs we want to merge into destination image
$a = imagecreatefrompng('https://rickwgrundy.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/pt509_stick_figure_podium_speaking-348x370.png');
$b = imagecreatefrompng('400x400.png');

//copy each png file on top of the destination (result) png
imagecopy($dest_image, $a, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
imagecopy($dest_image, $b, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

//send the appropriate headers and save the image in the given link name
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest_image, "result.png", 9);

//destroy all the image resources to free up memory
imagedestroy($a);
imagedestroy($b);
imagedestroy($dest_image);
```

Comment: can u give more detail on this actually what u want

Comment: Here is everything what can i provide. I don't have anything else.

Comment: u want to merge local image from online image ?

Comment: __I want to merge these two image__ as said in post.

Comment: merge means overlap two images over eachother

Comment: Yes... See the example image in my post, I already attach and also post a sample online image in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of
`imagecopy($dest_image, $a, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);` you need to copy AND resize the image using `imagecopyresized` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

So you need this to replace `imagecopy($dest_image, $a, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);` with:

```
$image_current_width = imagesx($a);
$image_current_height = imagesy($a);
imagecopyresized($dest_image, $a, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, $image_current_width , $image_current_height );
```

This will resize your image while it copies it across.

Comment: Not working.. Now the image looks like - [http://imgur.com/](http://imgur.com/a/q9Crr)

Comment: Hey, Somehow i managed to workable with the `imagecopyresized(....)`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

yes Is it possible but your web image not 400x400 . your web image 348X370 so. if your  local image 348X370 it is 100% work properly . i try my local image base on your web image then working . 
[my image and your web image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zblio.png)

and my code here

```
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x,$src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct)
{
$cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
}

$image1 = imagecreatefrompng('https://rickwgrundy.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/pt509_stick_figure_podium_speaking-348x370.png'); //348 x 370
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('b.png'); //348 x 370
imagealphablending($image1, false);
imagesavealpha($image1, true);

imagecopymerge_alpha($image1, $image2, 10, 9, 0, 0, 348, 370, 100);
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($image1);
```

Comment: About 22 min ago of your answer i got my one and thanks for your time.